# Cherry-pick modules with Rollup and ES Modules?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, configuration, rollup, rollupjs

With lodash-es, we can cherry-pick modules like this: `import drop from 'lodash/drop';` This way only `drop` gets used and nothing else.

How do I achieve the same thing with Rollup?

I'm configuring a react & typescript ui library to be used in two create-react-app projects. I learned that using esm is best for my use case and it's the most affective way to achieve treeshaking with Rollup. However, when I use my library, I'm importing like this: `import { someComponent }from 'my-ui-library';` is this singling out `someComponent` like the cherry-pick method above. Does the syntax matter?

Here is my `rollup.config.js`:

```
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';
import svgr from '@svgr/rollup';
import url from '@rollup/plugin-url';
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';
import external from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import includePaths from 'rollup-plugin-includepaths';

const pkg = require('./package.json');

export default {
  cache: false,
  input: 'src/index.ts',
  output: [{ file: pkg.module, format: 'esm' }],
  treeshake: true,
  plugins: [
    external({
      preferBuiltins: false,
    }),
    babel({
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      plugins: ['external-helpers'],
      externalHelpers: true, // Exclude babel helpers.
    }),
    json(),
    resolve(),
    svgr({
      ref: true,
      svgo: false,
    }),
    typescript({
      clean: true,
      typescript: require('typescript'),
    }),
    url(),
    includePaths({
      paths: ['src'],
    }),
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be a few catches when tree-shaking ESM packages. The first catch is that tree shaking only works in production and the second catch is that your `package.json` must contain a `sideEffects: false` property. Unfortunately, in development, tree shaking still imports the entire library to retrieve the named export. Click [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) more info about webpack tree-shaking.

For example (in development): [import screenshot exmaple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouVrB.png)

In the example above, I'm importing a named export called `defaultLayoutCommands`; however, it still shows that all of the library was imported, even though webpack is utilizing the `esm` file. However, if I separate the file and import that directly, then it shows the smaller import size. In production, this ***should*** tree-shake import the `defaultLayoutCommands` and be just like the second import example. That said, tree-shaking only works with webpack **AND** ESM.

When working with CJS/UMD/AMD, tree-shaking won't work. Instead, you'll have to combine all of your exports to a single class/object (like an `exports` object). Then using ES6 destructuring, you can pull off that method.

For example, lodash has all the functions within a single file, for example:

```
    function throttle(func, wait, options) {
      var leading = true,
      trailing = true;

      if (typeof func != 'function') {
        throw new TypeError(FUNC_ERROR_TEXT);
      }
      if (isObject(options)) {
        leading = 'leading' in options ? !!options.leading : leading;
        trailing = 'trailing' in options ? !!options.trailing : trailing;
      }
      return debounce(func, wait, {
       'leading': leading,
       'maxWait': wait,
       'trailing': trailing
     });
   }
```

And then attaches that function as a method to an object:

```
lodash.add = add;
lodash.attempt = attempt;
lodash.camelCase = camelCase;
...
lodash.throttle = throttle;
lodash.thru = thru;
lodash.toArray = toArray;
...etc
```

And then using an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) exports the `lodash` object. The nice thing about this is that you can require multiple named imports at once:

```
const { get, debounce, isEmpty } = require("lodash");
```

The disadvantage is that you're requiring the entire lodash object. So, to get around this, they have separate files (and/or npm packages!!!) to limit the imports to just what's needed. So, they have included additional files like this in the root package folder:

```
...js
get.js
debounce.js
isEmpty.js
...js
```

However, the disadvantage with this, is that you'll now have three imports:

```
const get = require("lodash/get");
const debounce = require("lodash/debounce");
const isEmpty = require("lodash/isEmpty");
```

But! You'll have an overall smaller import size... however, the package size is larger! So to mitigate this, they broke up some of the popular methods into their own separate packages: [lodash.get](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.get), l[odash.debounce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.debounce), and [lodash.isEmpty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.isempty)!

So, in summation, if you don't plan on utilizing CJS/UMD/AMD (like lodash does), then tree-shaking will work as expected in **production** when using **webpack** and **ESM** packages within the **client**. However, if you are including additional builds for more compatibility, then you'll have to create an array of rollup configs with different `inputs` and different `outputs`.

For example:

```
const resolutions = {
    globals: {
        react: "React",
        "react-is": "reactIs",
    },
    exports: "named",
};

export default [
  {
    input: "./src/index.js", // this transforms the entire source
    output: [
        {
            file: pkg.main,
            format: "cjs",
            ...resolutions,
        },
        {
            file: pkg.fallback,
            format: "umd",
            name: "My-Example-Library",
            ...resolutions,
        },
        {
            file: pkg.module,
            format: "esm",
            ...resolutions,
        },
    ],
    ...etc
  },
  {
    input: "./src/components/example.js", // this transforms just an "example.js" file and ouputs to a "dist/example.[build].js" file
    output: [
        {
            file: "dist/example.cjs.js,
            format: "cjs",
            ...resolutions,
        },
        {
            file: dist/example.umd.js,
            format: "umd",
            name: "My-Example",
            ...resolutions,
        },
    ],
    ...etc
  }
]
```

More info about use cases for the different builds can be found [here](https://dev.to/iggredible/what-the-heck-are-cjs-amd-umd-and-esm-ikm) and an example Rollup config can be found [here](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/react-smde/blob/master/rollup.config.js).